# Fetch data from two table in a php file

Tags: php, mysql

i have online store and i want to make an api for it
i have a three tables in MySql database i Should use to fetch the product details
`file_path` for the product image url
`invetory_details`  for price
`tbl_product`  for the product details like (name , description, digital or  physical...etc)
i didn't know how to fetch data from more than one table  please help me with this.
this is my code i was able to fetch data from one table

```
  define('DB_HOST','localhost');
  define('DB_USER','admin');
  define('DB_PASS','123456');
  define('DB_NAME','testname');
  
  $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      die('error'.mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  $stmt = $conn->prepare( "SELECT id, upc_code, category_id, sub_category_id, sub_subcategory_id, name, description, brand_id , digital, license_key_code, active , added_by_id, sort_order, rating, added_at, updated_at FROM tbl_product;");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($id, $upc_code, $category_id, $sub_category_id, $sub_subcategory_id, $name, $description, $brand_id, $digital, $license_key_code, $active, $added_by_id, $sort_order, $rating, $added_at, $updated_at);
  $product= array();
  
  while($stmt->fetch()){
      $temp=array();
      $temp['id']=$id;
      $temp['upc_code']=$upc_code;
      $temp['category_id']=$category_id;
      $temp['sub_category_id']=$sub_category_id;
      $temp['sub_subcategory_id']=$sub_subcategory_id;
      $temp['name']=$name;
      $temp['digital']=$digital;
      $temp['active']=$active;
      $temp['added_by_id']=$added_by_id;
      $temp['sort_order']=$sort_order;
      $temp['rating']=$rating;
      $temp['added_at']=$added_at;
      $temp['updated_at']=$updated_at;
      
      array_push($product, $temp);
  }
  echo json_encode($product);
```

Comment: Fetchng results from multiple tables is done the same way as fetching from one table. Processing the results may be different. Pls describe what you would like to do with the fetched data and if these multiple tables relate to each other.

Comment: hello and thank you for your time yes the tables  are connected to each other , i want to fetch data from a multiple tables to get the the product details and then use it to build an android app please check this link 
[link](https://digtalstore.com/Api/api.php)

Comment: Then you need to use a join to link these tables together on common field(s).

Comment: can you please writ me an example? i am a beginner in this  domain thank you for your assistance i really appreciate it

Comment: Pls check out the answers to the duplicate question for an example.